# postgres tunning does not any efficiency

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with more than 10GB data.
My server has 16GB of RAM (Ubuntu server is my OS).

I tried too tune Postgres in order too decrease the time of query execution
but with every tuning config, just 1GB of ram was used.

Here is my tuning config:

- DB Version: 9.6
- OS Type: linux
- DB Type: desktop
- Total Memory (RAM): 16 GB
- Number of Connections: 100

config:

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 4GB
work_mem = 8738kB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
min_wal_size = 100MB
max_wal_size = 100MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.5
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
```

Any advice and suggestion will be appreciated...

Comment: Increase [`shared_buffers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-BUFFERS) to 4GB (25% of available RAM). If you do *lots* of large *sorts*, increase also your [`work_mem`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) to somewhere around 20 MB (more, if the number of *actual* connections performing *sorts* at the same time is far less than 100).

Comment: See also: [Linux tuning to improve PostgreSQL performance](https://www.slideshare.net/PostgreSQL-Consulting/linux-tuning-to-improve-postgresql-performance) and [Performance Optimization](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) although some of it is a bit outdated.

Comment: PostgreSQL also uses the file system cache, so it probably uses more than the 1GB shared memory. Try to find out which queries are taking too much time and tune those. Often there is just an index missing.